# How to save text from input to variable in angular?

Tags: html, angular

I'm trying to take text from one of my component.html files and save the input to a variable in a method in one of my .ts files. Can you help?

### home.component.html file:

```
Username: <input ng-model="username"><br>
Password: <input ng-model="pass">  
<button (click)="login()">Login</button>
```

### home.component.ts file:

```
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

    login()
    {
     const usr= {{username}};
     const password={{pass}};
     print("user is"+usr " Password is"+password);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using angular it should be

**`ngModel`** instead of **`ng-model`**

```
Username: <input  [(ngModel)]="username"><br>
Password: <input  [(ngModel)]="pass">
```

and in component.ts

```
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
    username : string;
    password : string;

    login()
    {
     const usr= this.username;
     const password= this.password;
     console.log("user is"+usr " Password is"+password);
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks. how do I return the values of "usr" and "password" back to the html instead of writing to console?

Comment: why do you want to retun? its already there in HTML. you can use it as {{user}} {{password}}

Comment: I'm actually returning different text, I just want to understand how to

Answer (score 0):

you need to change ng-model to ngModel

> **ng-model** :- angularjs
>
> **ngModel** :- Angular 2 or greater

**Html**

```
Username: <input [(ngModel)]="username"><br>
Password: <input [(ngModel)]="pass">  
<button (click)="login()">Login</button>
```

> Component

```
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
 public username: String;
 public pass: String;
 public function login() {
 console.log('User Name: ' + this.username);
 console.log('Password: ' + this.pass);
 }
}
```